# Spring WebClient and jsonPath - How to output json result if test fails

Tags: spring-boot, testing, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

We are testing with WebTestClient (SpringBoot) our GraphQL Backend and have problems to see why exactly the test failed. Our code looks like this:

```
webTestClient
   .post().uri(GQLKonstanten.URL)
   .body(GQLRequestInserter.from(movieDeleteGQL, variables))
   .exchange()
   .expectBody()
   .jsonPath("$.errors").doesNotExist()
   .jsonPath("$.data.movie.id")
   .isEqualTo(movie.getId());
```

What I get is a stacktrace with the following message:

> java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.data.movie.id"
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Missing
>   property in path $['data']['movie']

The error message is completely correct. But to actually SEE what this graphQl Exceution actually command returned I always change the WebClient execution into:

```
String responseBody = webTestClient
  .post().uri(GQLKonstanten.URL)
  .body(GQLRequestInserter.from(deleteMovieGQL, variables))
  .exchange()
  .expectStatus()
  .isOk()
  .expectBody(String.class)
  .returnResult().getResponseBody();
System.out.print(responseBody);
```

Then I see the result as

```
{"data":{"deleteMovie":{"id":7}}}
```

and I see that I expected "movie" instead of "deleteMovie" property. so I change my test to

```
.jsonPath("$.data.deleteMovie.id")
```

Always running the test twice and changing the code is cumbersome.

Is there a better way to let WebTestClient always output the responseBody when the test fails?

Comment: have you tested to just use the `.log()` function?

Comment: I don't know what log function do you mean. I found a better way with                 .consumeWith(System.out::println) after expectBody()

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Best way I found so far is to add a

```
.expectBody()
.consumeWith(System.out::println)
```

It prints out the json result always and not on error only. But it works for me.